# How to force Phonegap Build to include a resource during build

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm building an app with Adobe Phonegap Build. I have one strange issue: my custom fonts work perfectly when testing the app on my device locally, but they do not work when uploading the app to phonegap build. 
After some research I stumbled upon the following article: 
http://www.stuartarthurmorris.com/2014/10/phonegap-build-missing-fonts/

It highlights the problem:

> that there was a resources folder “res” created when initializing the
>   environment (not     sure if PhoneGap, cordova or Ionic scripts are to
>   blame here). During build, the res     contents are not included
>   unless they are specifically referenced in the config.xml file (like
>   the splash screens and icons.)

Now I understand the cause of the problem, but I don't like the proposed solution (move the files to another folder). I don't want to change the structure of my app, I'd rather force phonegap to include those files editing the config.xml file. Nonetheless I wasn't able to find a way to reference the res folder in my config.xml. How can I do it?